# Android 9 can't create directory inside Android external public path("storage/emulated/0/MyImages")

Tags: java, android, android-9.0-pie

I want to create a directory inside Android external public path(`"storage/emulated/0/MyImages"`).

The code is running on Android 9. All run-time permissions to writing on external storage are granted.

Tried code like this.

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyImages");
if (!dir.exists) {
  dir.mkdirs();
}
```

The `dir` variable has path - `"/storage/emulated/0/MyImages"`.

`dir.mkdirs()` always returns `false`. There is short log from LogCat:

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
W/System.err: at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
W/System.err: at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
W/System.err: at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
```

Comment: This code [will not work on Android Q (by default) and Android R+ (for all apps)](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html). So, you should strongly consider moving away from this anyway.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the response, I'm agree. But I'm confused why is it impossible to create directory? File Manager app on device with same permissions can create.

Comment: My guess is that there is a problem in your runtime permissions logic, but that is just a guess.

Comment: @CommonsWare OMG, there is my fall. I'm checking for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions, but requesting for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, spent a day and a half and just now noticed. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check permission if yes then call your function else to call showPhoneStatePermission

Add permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

private void showPhoneStatePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            showExplanation("Permission Needed", "Rationale", Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, REQUEST_PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        } else {
            requestPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, REQUEST_PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission (already) Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG, there is my fall. I'm checking for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions, but requesting for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, spent a day and a half and just now noticed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create directories with uppercase characters in the name in the external storage directory(/sdcard)!!??  (If you solved the other issues like permissions on whatever version of Android you are using...) It seems you can't have uppercase characters (at least in android-32).

'dir.mkdir()' in .../Android/Sdk/sources/android-32/java.io.File.java eventually calls 'fs.createDirecty(this)', where FileSystem fs = DefaultFileSystem.getFileSystem();  where fs is an instance of the class UnixFileSystem   fs.createDirectory calls 'createDirectory0 which is a native method.  Something in there seems not to like creating directories with uppercase characters.

It can create directories with uppercase letters within directories in /storage/emulated/0/, but in in /storage/emulated/0 itself.  I can't understand why they would do that -- unless it has some idea that things in /storage/emulated/0 are: 1) the start of java 'package' names that must be lowercase or 2: to force a first level directories to be 'compatible' between Windows (which ignores case) and Linux (which respects case).

Note that the 'mkdir' command run in the shell or from adb can create directories with upper case characters in /sdcard (/storage/emulated/0)